# capture with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like "ListUI_col_order[01234567][5]". I'd like to capture the two numeric sequences from the string. The last part between the square brackets may contain 2 digits, while the first numeric sequence always contains 8 digits (And the numbers are dynamically changing of course.) Im doing this in javascript and the code for the first part is simple: I get the only 8digit sequence from the string:

```
var str = $(this).attr('id');
var unique = str.match(/([0-9]){8}/g);
```

Getting the second part is a bit complicated to me. I cannot simply use:

```
var column = str.match(/[0-9]{1,2}/g)
```

Because this will match '01', '23', '45', '67', '5' in our example, It's clear. Although I'm able to get the information what I need as column[4], because the first part always contains 8 digits, but I'd like a nicer way to retrieve the last number.
So I define the contex and I can tell the regex that Im looking for a 1 or 2 digit number which has square brackets directly before and after it:

```
var column = str.match(/\[[0-9]{1,2}\]/g)
// this will return [5]. which is nearly what I want
```

So to get Only the numeric data I use parenthesis to capture only the numbers like:

```
 var column = str.match(/\[([0-9]){1,2}\]/g)
 // this will result in:
 // column[0] = '[5]'
 // column[1] = [5]
```

So my question is how to match the '[5]' but only capture the '5'? I have only the [0-9] between the parenthesis, but this will still capture the square brackets as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get both numbers in one go :

```
var m = str.match(/\[(\d{8})\]\[(\d{1,2})\]$/)
```

For your example, this makes `["[01234567][5]", "01234567", "5"]`

To get both matches as numbers, you can then do

```
if (m) return m.slice(1).map(Number)
```

which builds `[1234567, 5]`

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I'll accept your answer and use this method, but I still would like to know: why does `/\[([0-9]){1,2}\]/g` capture the square itself too? And to answer my own question: I accidentally omitted the 'g' flag and it worked...but dont know why?

Comment: When you use the g flag, you ask for multiple matches. This isn't compatible, using the `match` function, with capturing submatches. You may use the `exec` function.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not support the lookbehind necessary to do this. In other languages such as PHP, it'd be as simple as `/(?<=\[)\d{1,2}(?=\])/`, but in JavaScript I am not aware of any way to do this other than use a capturing subpattern as you are here, and getting that index from the result array.

Side-note, it's usually better to put the quantifier *inside* the capturing group - otherwise you're repeating the group itself, not its contents!